# Google Maps API missing alt_id

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Here it says that any alternative `place_id`'s will be returned in an array: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#multiple-ids

Further documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) and [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResults) shows that any alternative id's will be returned under `alt_ids`, as shown in the examples.

I tried this both through the browser and through the python `googlemaps` library, and neither were returned with `alt_ids`.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0&key=YOUR_API_KEY

In fact, querying by the `alt_id` shown in the documentation as `D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk` resulted in `googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError: INVALID_REQUEST`, or in the browser `"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"`:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Google Places API's Support Page [sent me here to StackOverflow](https://developers.google.com/places/support), hope you guys can tell me about this oddity or if I'm mistaken about something.

---

JSON returned via browser:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "5",
            "short_name" : "5",
            "types" : [ "floor" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "48",
            "short_name" : "48",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name" : "Pirrama Rd",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "New South Wales",
            "short_name" : "NSW",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Australia",
            "short_name" : "AU",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "2009",
            "short_name" : "2009",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "5, \u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003e48 Pirrama Rd\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003ePyrmont\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eNSW\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e2009\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eAustralia\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "5, 48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "(02) 9374 4000",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -33.8666113,
            "lng" : 151.1958324
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
      "international_phone_number" : "+61 2 9374 4000",
      "name" : "Google",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : false,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "1730"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "0830"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "1730"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "0830"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "1730"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "0830"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "1730"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "0830"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "0830"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM",
            "Tuesday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM",
            "Wednesday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM",
            "Thursday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM",
            "Friday: 8:30 AM – 5:00 PM",
            "Saturday: Closed",
            "Sunday: Closed"
         ]
      },
      "photos" : [
         {
            "height" : 960,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100919424873665842845/photos\"\u003eDonnie Piercey\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAU3wmS35nuxnOk2tcFwH3NYQMzwHLctqPA4phgAjWG8exKv_5m78v0UHmerSVmrzzIKE0tKfEdTqMcAHkTiLw0bWL-fyyvXoPAXRAotZg9wuKjH5fj8QdkhTmzCn2p7sMEhBlQG6P4kyofNlfThhN0TmfGhQQLs8LkCaO-U7CZmarOQsgj9C4gg",
            "width" : 1280
         },
         {
            "height" : 1365,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105932078588305868215/photos\"\u003eMaksym Kozlenko\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAA0AvSogp7ZPWvnB2rsqm7FWOenJ1Z84NIkMyj2kOXEvpp3qa1fjY9fcwfosQSsvG-328VQEUurQ8sLWHL78XMv7g8IMIEfYGw1v53wCxbVpqZtIXV6IqUUrmA6eliwldEhCW4fXsJND4GrxdPhl3ef9aGhTByfDbEMusTc8VZaVUAfFH2Uvspg",
            "width" : 2048
         },
         {
            "height" : 2368,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108508601154030859314/photos\"\u003eLeo Angelo George\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAA5oe21xN1_VMhXfZXgmPyVk9j_m37TkPPDahrdPrbl04QIoajmnyOcofgichznJECYOaznhlf1-A-GhN0czidtrNnPRtLwXBCf0_VBfaILeQoEpqnYm55yLCqrRaOP-QHEhDFNFZf-R-6ztgzE4buqqNqGhRj1jOU72hSaqO7flBhiP2oFg59ug",
            "width" : 3200
         },
         {
            "height" : 1131,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105637462841200316207/photos\"\u003eFrom a Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAA3--DtrTWRxZPA0g_Ej18bg9YBrT_iNP5UPC1KYuNk8zuvB11952cz2x1cyuD9gaPqIPchSjxkHalNlXBDKt3eO-Y7dWokIkPCbbbGmzEiCk80d3TCkpxPnW5NStk126uEhCgKTqcXZRddb3kNGHKPakBGhTo0vj7mVd20M5w0D1LkIsuY2AC6g",
            "width" : 1600
         },
         {
            "height" : 2184,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114701241123617315548/photos\"\u003eMargaret Lee\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAA-iZAmof-HPdfIAfxPPHlD2iL3SMlpFuZgZckDaV0ezo-rfX8ORzZA-DI2K6l0x0iJvMG6zkgXq8M027UqYu9QEBpvUqTZg4NEcPHu9CKRxI1sB0UqIL7bqhKrjiSm7HYEhCzVzvVoQnGkE4PDewcbSOyGhRQ0oLDDhDPlMSqqshawcK7YtSNew",
            "width" : 2911
         },
         {
            "height" : 1536,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104177669626132953795/photos\"\u003eJustine OBRIEN\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAyW321TV_2ZCprgrGuc8FORmBKN4xc49DZDVtXBXS54zFfZJ0egb8e-BKRjh_yhLOWfR24xgJx7nrTW9kIIoGzC0RNINNKoLGqSU6htuydl0IhoN4dnyuybpNwOYRnAkpEhA01ud2Sig_MUSGCWP1U3wFGhR_IBXXAsi9qmSaCIDXz6CaNGCO2Q",
            "width" : 2048
         },
         {
            "height" : 608,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116750797999944764767/photos\"\u003eJessica Pfund\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAADbRHDpuIqFe-m4vbLOcgTXjSuCb3O5oCUuIYz1brH1bJJ6J5SWPYZKcqLDfTy2SL_j02NNTkBVtts824pt8c3epQpxpZ2bw1y6fK0_N3GC8pX7ye9B_KUQfIFHbYRE83EhBSpMGzss4lmFjMXIvCnniiGhQjD1YrZjXt7ubRHbwBB4Xsqx3zGg",
            "width" : 1080
         },
         {
            "height" : 612,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114701241123617315548/photos\"\u003eMargaret Lee\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAANkWnV43a_uW2O0HiQrz9kS2OSIIedZc7wCMcTaG7uT8y8_5fQeLF-uHkm_Buu68FxclKVic4N8PYvvr8j0eb9nPSWdm6YDPGXrtceT1NvZruWQDg5cqcjGuSOnc85ftdEhCAjJspccx3PEo6ohdczK9gGhQdb8KFUahTpzGoFwwb0ahek2m2xA",
            "width" : 816
         },
         {
            "height" : 2322,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107252953636064841537/photos\"\u003eWilliam Stewart\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAt8-2VEklpEuHu-S3j6WCb_bLCNoPrnuMIr9rjE7HGjx4W7kKUuqR_d7TW7uyG96yc5r986R830-TXlhkUcIlqtxR7bv3sGcLTrWOfwIhC0GpmJbC6Wv0ybPD-mnRohwwEhA5qURsC2Xtp8K7FweldZgIGhSCipPyqSfeAQIadRV0M0rCmCBoUQ",
            "width" : 4128
         },
         {
            "height" : 1224,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102793072679802771755/photos\"\u003eKeith Denny\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAuQhV8wWw0kRb7MJdy6L46Fht0KfCPUEZwVlwONs_CiEng0IG5lsecycfT1WEm1a0Lqwe7NjpATMLf5RaR_GPDiPGsUCpuLZA2-q-dzOcH8P8OJfkkVM58PdTIithnNuXEhAzY4RXHTtOD8VgHQYnF_-8GhRRzjGakfekcq0Ge9u_iKshhHlFdQ",
            "width" : 1632
         }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
      "rating" : 4.4,
      "reference" : "CmRaAAAARUnabgoDUbptx7jmkjMZFNyM0ho4QO3Q0OknonZMWW5r8ctfDbJgSMUhyXnBaGYsnE8kaap-1d0dP48iN61kc1ArzGAwjxQCnZKPePuInJ4uaVexmwPIZFXDk1LRu6sqEhCeQ4-Mk2lGOJ5RbAD71wkqGhT0MpaqpHHxQr6pulLi6pQ_799NNw",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Justine OBRIEN",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/104177669626132953795",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-s6AzNe5Qcco/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFTE/NvVzCuI-jMI/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "text" : "Google Sydney is located on Darling Island on the glorious Sydney Harbour in a prime position easy to get to for staff and visitors. The reception has an excellent fresh living wall and the staff are welcoming, pleasant and friendly, ready to assist you with bountiful information for all inquiries. All ready to *do the right thing* Always helping *Go Get IT*, the right information to *Gather IT*, from all the right places plus *Give IT* at all the right times to all the right people! \nGo Get Gather Give Google excellence personified at Google Sydney! Thanks Google Sydney!",
            "time" : 1451482843
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Danielle Lonnon",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/118257578392162991040",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-laqORDSvktk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAApfw/hX9vqf6fJ2g/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "text" : "As someone who works in the theatre, I don't find the Google offices nerdy, I find it magical and theatrical. Themed rooms  with useful props and big sets with unique and charismatic characters. You sure this isn't a theatre company? Oh no wait Google has money, while the performing art does not.",
            "time" : 1425790392
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Josh Kingston",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/116686571356940046569",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-dN2o7SFZSeI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAEDw/ya9vvWx-cVo/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "text" : "An Enlightened stronghold. Glyph hack those level 8 portals.",
            "time" : 1451709974
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Lachlan Martin",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/101767769287488554641",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-TuBhQ6C9ViI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACcY/3Web5Iqk6vg/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "text" : "The cool-aid here tastes amazing!!! ",
            "time" : 1439790358
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 0,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Lyn Bayliss",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/116677609452593302785",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7OYAbqKTsPo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACDw/wkM_ex5cHXM/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 1,
            "text" : "Google Sydney reception desk recorded messaging service is a shocker and doesn't align with the hipster, groovy Google that we all know and love.....blah!",
            "time" : 1449715765
         }
      ],
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554",
      "user_ratings_total" : 117,
      "utc_offset" : 660,
      "vicinity" : "5 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
      "website" : "https://www.google.com.au/about/careers/locations/sydney/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

JSON returned via Python library `googlemaps`:

```
{
   'result':{  
      'types':[  
         'point_of_interest',
         'establishment'
      ],
      'name':'Google',
      'icon':'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png',
      'url':'https://maps.google.com/?cid=10281119596374313554',
      'formatted_address':'5, 48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia',
      'scope':'GOOGLE',
      'international_phone_number':'+61 2 9374 4000',
      'address_components':[  
         {  
            'short_name':'5',
            'types':[  
               'floor'
            ],
            'long_name':'5'
         },
         {  
            'short_name':'48',
            'types':[  
               'street_number'
            ],
            'long_name':'48'
         },
         {  
            'short_name':'Pirrama Rd',
            'types':[  
               'route'
            ],
            'long_name':'Pirrama Road'
         },
         {  
            'short_name':'Pyrmont',
            'types':[  
               'locality',
               'political'
            ],
            'long_name':'Pyrmont'
         },
         {  
            'short_name':'NSW',
            'types':[  
               'administrative_area_level_1',
               'political'
            ],
            'long_name':'New South Wales'
         },
         {  
            'short_name':'AU',
            'types':[  
               'country',
               'political'
            ],
            'long_name':'Australia'
         },
         {  
            'short_name':'2009',
            'types':[  
               'postal_code'
            ],
            'long_name':'2009'
         }
      ],
      'formatted_phone_number':'(02) 9374 4000',
      'website':'https://www.google.com.au/about/careers/locations/sydney/',
      'id':'4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7',
      'reference':'CmRaAAAAFwTQO5LeVNJc_sog-WaEcH4RjJySPbl4MRp6Qpt-bTbLhbqhE2qi4SuWNl3OvnQ7qUTnWxcwv9lMzv211uvLukLxJHZCBy8rvST9LddkearXrkBIEEy-TBsViGeKE1zQEhBS3YBx75-VlS4Kbsrs-g_gGhQIDybgoVneX_XCmrVEWZr7idNqtg',
      'place_id':'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4',
      'opening_hours':{  
         'periods':[  
            {  
               'close':{  
                  'time':'1730',
                  'day':1
               },
               'open':{  
                  'time':'0830',
                  'day':1
               }
            },
            {  
               'close':{  
                  'time':'1730',
                  'day':2
               },
               'open':{  
                  'time':'0830',
                  'day':2
               }
            },
            {  
               'close':{  
                  'time':'1730',
                  'day':3
               },
               'open':{  
                  'time':'0830',
                  'day':3
               }
            },
            {  
               'close':{  
                  'time':'1730',
                  'day':4
               },
               'open':{  
                  'time':'0830',
                  'day':4
               }
            },
            {  
               'close':{  
                  'time':'1700',
                  'day':5
               },
               'open':{  
                  'time':'0830',
                  'day':5
               }
            }
         ],
         'weekday_text':[  
            'Monday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM',
            'Tuesday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM',
            'Wednesday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM',
            'Thursday: 8:30 AM – 5:30 PM',
            'Friday: 8:30 AM – 5:00 PM',
            'Saturday: Closed',
            'Sunday: Closed'
         ],
         'open_now':False
      },
      'reviews':[  
         {  
            'author_url':'https://plus.google.com/104177669626132953795',
            'rating':5,
            'language':'en',
            'text':'Google Sydney is located on Darling Island on the glorious Sydney Harbour in a prime position easy to get to for staff and visitors. The reception has an excellent fresh living wall and the staff are welcoming, pleasant and friendly, ready to assist you with bountiful information for all inquiries. All ready to *do the right thing* Always helping *Go Get IT*, the right information to *Gather IT*, from all the right places plus *Give IT* at all the right times to all the right people! \nGo Get Gather Give Google excellence personified at Google Sydney! Thanks Google Sydney!',
            'time':1451482843,
            'profile_photo_url':'//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-s6AzNe5Qcco/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFTE/NvVzCuI-jMI/photo.jpg',
            'aspects':[  
               {  
                  'rating':3,
                  'type':'overall'
               }
            ],
            'author_name':'Justine OBRIEN'
         },
         {  
            'author_url':'https://plus.google.com/118257578392162991040',
            'rating':5,
            'language':'en',
            'text':"As someone who works in the theatre, I don't find the Google offices nerdy, I find it magical and theatrical. Themed rooms  with useful props and big sets with unique and charismatic characters. You sure this isn't a theatre company? Oh no wait Google has money, while the performing art does not.",
            'time':1425790392,
            'profile_photo_url':'//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-laqORDSvktk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAApfw/hX9vqf6fJ2g/photo.jpg',
            'aspects':[  
               {  
                  'rating':3,
                  'type':'overall'
               }
            ],
            'author_name':'Danielle Lonnon'
         },
         {  
            'author_url':'https://plus.google.com/116686571356940046569',
            'rating':5,
            'language':'en',
            'text':'An Enlightened stronghold. Glyph hack those level 8 portals.',
            'time':1451709974,
            'profile_photo_url':'//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-dN2o7SFZSeI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAEDw/ya9vvWx-cVo/photo.jpg',
            'aspects':[  
               {  
                  'rating':3,
                  'type':'overall'
               }
            ],
            'author_name':'Josh Kingston'
         },
         {  
            'author_url':'https://plus.google.com/101767769287488554641',
            'rating':5,
            'language':'en',
            'text':'The cool-aid here tastes amazing!!! ',
            'time':1439790358,
            'profile_photo_url':'//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-TuBhQ6C9ViI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACcY/3Web5Iqk6vg/photo.jpg',
            'aspects':[  
               {  
                  'rating':3,
                  'type':'overall'
               }
            ],
            'author_name':'Lachlan Martin'
         },
         {  
            'author_url':'https://plus.google.com/116677609452593302785',
            'rating':1,
            'language':'en',
            'text':"Google Sydney reception desk recorded messaging service is a shocker and doesn't align with the hipster, groovy Google that we all know and love.....blah!",
            'time':1449715765,
            'profile_photo_url':'//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7OYAbqKTsPo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACDw/wkM_ex5cHXM/photo.jpg',
            'aspects':[  
               {  
                  'rating':0,
                  'type':'overall'
               }
            ],
            'author_name':'Lyn Bayliss'
         }
      ],
      'adr_address':'5, <span class="street-address">48 Pirrama Rd</span>, <span class="locality">Pyrmont</span> <span class="region">NSW</span> <span class="postal-code">2009</span>, <span class="country-name">Australia</span>',
      'rating':4.4,
      'vicinity':'5 48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont',
      'photos':[  
         {  
            'width':1280,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAAAFGroRwnVSiIpPP8xt-PKnVfkwpIaUDLC5yqxqHzWUMD3fZpSMIyD6syDsGL3dkXWz7jrnnHxpkh3qCjbUfzB2F4DSH-JQLQ-qW4mZyojOOwlj8A1XVceduF0oEfgHqbEhDRYd7EhaRibtisKjGzs1nmGhQmEqwEtFnn7_y4yCRiYOXixeTwxw',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100919424873665842845/photos">Donnie Piercey</a>'
            ],
            'height':960
         },
         {  
            'width':2048,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAADQKS7SyoBuHtwAaF0szY9NOnmQ0KkIalzeUA86SNlrx-R_b6NZ6uobTTvHAryZetdJomLeFVR-l26EcX2Imc6rdvaQHB8Pu9Ap8mi4HK4x9pyh2X28Xa41uds1rofT4AEhB5iJ7Xb1wfmukgWdUPU5qVGhS62mDgtN47W_1kkR-WrIzBYwHxrQ',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105932078588305868215/photos">Maksym Kozlenko</a>'
            ],
            'height':1365
         },
         {  
            'width':3200,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAAV18AQpoPo4Jw3dbhRubQghJavXV_wRJAaJe7Lff9d4lmQdraNNdgpbuJMnhpCZxs7jYDJdnZmvfWz3zcata4n5Wog7Sxd0Nm3nlvaABwZgsUK9IlgyTJ_3FLaTikKceVEhAwbUgZ3g0YtU-wSr-6ogkAGhQDWSfaqadzmmOBrKvWpgpjzqyO7A',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108508601154030859314/photos">Leo Angelo George</a>'
            ],
            'height':2368
         },
         {  
            'width':1600,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAAu4UwCSySN8VGZFtGOYDtr6TXuZ0CQt2_bujy9Npyfxsof-mNf-IX2Iz_YaMCid-VKvf8K2kuYwIXHUBi3WzdCxMRdW-hV27aeWMkmu2wjiJh_l-nBo8QYuCCaIlOzC1kEhDhtDOUfuioyKsPLU_KYzroGhRhJcNIx7rj1Q8k4avVKlvZonkHFQ',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105637462841200316207/photos">From a Google User</a>'
            ],
            'height':1131
         },
         {  
            'width':2911,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAANHUF6JBhb2IUEpnNY7rDF5_UJPeRuQ6FwMYZ-UJ5qmxLqf5b1CNibRftoKjnZVJQW7Op_SfBWUzLKIYy3lRmRHqVwrPCWgAjK92DSK7IDWZ5ijBIu8Z_-WllzTFdvmV6EhDCyK0mVot5b9CaUztziYc5GhR1OTTEVxMBwhaYeJvPNgOeJakv_g',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114701241123617315548/photos">Margaret Lee</a>'
            ],
            'height':2184
         },
         {  
            'width':2048,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAAxqCYgmnZwt1YF5TZ37vao33dVrJbJfX8MNpGQ_pZb3nTi8SXI907v8Hmx9XKvCO_8DKOMW9yyq3ZVHo6dP-0Mx8FwYdGrRG2pCmBdY5eJa0rVvP5iiDJUKRTCT2hbMvqEhA34C5_emCBRsL14DSxTT1GGhQhheE9tpLZfK8AgxTknrr_DbdWlw',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104177669626132953795/photos">Justine OBRIEN</a>'
            ],
            'height':1536
         },
         {  
            'width':1080,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAA4RSz4_OW32m3stm_jZYdW2xsrnmD2SuPRLj1yuLPEZG2r0TEYd3kNFRJ28eNDzeg_qhDxNS8SGhmn6ccnIIf585ZpWCRZY8gVUktqLaYZP61HvzW5RUdsgI5sNG8Y10mEhCxK0QxYY9XBEkGUH_pkr1NGhSDDNP3vM2ZC8LSJR-O6CHwdwGrLQ',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116750797999944764767/photos">Jessica Pfund</a>'
            ],
            'height':608
         },
         {  
            'width':816,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAAK_s9fda-27-_oNHZmal2ZOf7M1mOy2TSAuHhNdfI22nB5YYOA-74rACq6gy5ngnhxhAz9KYOw2DakpDWmyRNUILBTvWkKHpHELlN3VSaiMuol4X29m6poxcLDxz5WMyBEhD4Ay8isWujvhWccQjIe0LXGhSMwSqguFi0nOZfjze-GEgVyCG4uQ',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114701241123617315548/photos">Margaret Lee</a>'
            ],
            'height':612
         },
         {  
            'width':4128,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAAnZCp1N3thzDBC1Rq_lPGSeZWov8X73HkiXksleEyr5RIVM0kDGdZw9SDdIgbl8BeViOJ_56Z-livqIeA5-e-Vsf-XS3YPLGedSYH5FagMJWUuEfZaT0alX6umSlsP2jDEhDNjWgWGfNTtt_u6EpKITptGhSbKwnSUnLjHvPBL9v0CGCIJiUCKQ',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107252953636064841537/photos">William Stewart</a>'
            ],
            'height':2322
         },
         {  
            'width':1632,
            'photo_reference':'CmRdAAAAIMFo_fZSTk4TUwIuWVA04gnERP-uJ0VGJkVmEgf1YdA8wCGR_NubiE7_al0-HH1ZVkwrCDRqa_dBIYH8rp4qqHgyUurT2hAA5xgJkB9Ceyp0umpZymiTwQbGGkx6E_ffEhBO8j4SKIKJEtfQ3hrgWWKLGhTzj4aOY2HE4fydC1-fJIsvrhCZRw',
            'html_attributions':[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102793072679802771755/photos">Keith Denny</a>'
            ],
            'height':1224
         }
      ],
      'user_ratings_total':117,
      'utc_offset':660,
      'geometry':{  
         'location':{  
            'lng':151.1958324,
            'lat':-33.8666113
         }
      }
   },
   'html_attributions':[  

   ],
   'status':'OK'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using the [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) feature, the `alt_ids` and `scope` fields are probably not of any use to you.

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) says, `alt_ids` **may be empty or not present**.  It then says:

> The most likely reason for a place to have an alternative place ID is if your application adds a place and receives an application-scoped place ID, then later receives a Google-scoped place ID after passing the moderation process.

This is the case with the `D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk` Place ID shown in the example:

```
  "place_id" : "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
  "scope" : "GOOGLE",
  "alt_ids" : [
     {
        "place_id" : "D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
        "scope" : "APP"
     }
  ],
```

Note how `D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk` has **APP** scope, not **GOOGLE** scope.  That means it is a Place ID only usable by the app that added it (i.e. using API key from the same project in the Google Developers Console), which is why your details request for it fails.

Comment: Does this imply that besides passing moderation, there is rarely any change in Place ID? Ideally I'd like to find a definitive answer on whether or not the Place ID can be depended on to be a constant identifier for addresses.

Comment: Yes Place IDs change rarely.  They can change sometimes, the world is a complex, changing place.  And sometimes it depends on what your definition of "same place" is.  If a shop moves 2 doors down, is it the same place?  What if it changes its name slightly?  What if a cafe changes the name, but has the same menu, staff, prices, opening hours?  But in general, expect the same place to probably have the same Place ID over time.